# Laravel Query DB into Blade

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

It's possible query DB into Blade?
I send from routes to blade, all MyUsers and Booking.

Into table booking I've the  column id_user,

I've this code

```
    @foreach 
    {{$booking->id}}

this down Foreach is not optimized - it's possible improve it?
@foreach ($Myusers as $Myuser)
@if ($myuser == $booking->id_user)
$myuser->name 
@endif
@endforeach


    @endforeach
```

I've try with Blade::directive, but I can only send stirng value and not the php Value. i've this code

```
Blade::directive('DettagliUtente', function($expression) {
    print_r($expression); 
but echo the string "$booking->id_user" but I want the value $booking->iduser
   $dettaglioutente=\App\Utenti::find($var)->first();
   return "<?php echo '".$dettaglioutente->name."'; ?>";
        });


@DettagliUtente ($booking->id_user)
```

help me please

Comment: Would you please rephrase your question? Personally I do not understand what are you trying to achieve here.

Comment: Check the answer below

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to do something complex in the blade template you could do it by just adding a `<?php ... ?>` tag and do that there.
That being said, **PLEASE DON'T**, that is a bad practice, you should not have code, queries or any logic other than a simple IF or iteration on a template.
You should do the logic and fetching data from the actual code, not on the view, you need to separate concepts, views should not have code in them, just presenting data to the user.

From what I can see, the problem seems to be that you probably want something to show on every (or many) pages and of course you don't want to be repeating your self in every controller fetching the same data.

So, I'm going to propose to you for this kind of problems that you use **View Composers**. You can see the documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#view-composers

**How to use view composers**

You create a new Provider in `app/Providers`, you could call it `ViewComposerProvider`, in the `boot()` method you define a view composer:

```
View::composer('partials.my-books', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\MyBooksComposer');
```

Then you create that class and create a function `compose(View $view)` and there you can fetch the data, do any logic and finally send that data to the view:

```
$view->with('books', $my_list_of_books);
```

Then, all you need to do is to include that partial template into any template and Laravel will see that it needs to call the view composer for that partial template.

Your base template:

```
...
@include('partials.my-books')
...
```

Your partial template `app/resources/views/partials/my-books.blade.php`:

```
<ul>
@foreach($books as $book)
    <li>{{$book->name}}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

**Note:** Remember that you will need to register your provider `ViewComposerProvider` into your `config.app`

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your response, but i link User->name from booking->id_users